# undefined method '[]' for nil class rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

Why is this an undefined method? It says that the error is at this line:

```
  @member.room.update(rent: params[:member][:room_attributes][:rent], room_name: params[:member][:room_attributes][:room_name])
```

#### members_controller.rb

```
def edit
    @member = Member.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @member = Member.find(params[:id])
    @member.room.update(rent: params[:member][:room_attributes][:rent], room_name: params[:member][:room_attributes][:room_name])
end


def member_params
    params.require(:member).permit(:name, :room_id,
                                    room_attributes: [:rent, :room_name, :member_id],
                                    purchase_attributes: [:description, :cost, :member_id])
end
```

#### edit.html.erb

```
<h3> Member Name </h3><br>
<%= @member.name %><br>
  <%= form_for @member.room, url: member_path(@member) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :room_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :room_name %><br>
    <%= f.label :rent %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :rent %><br>


    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>

  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that one of your param keys is not set. When your form (in *edit.html.erb*) is output, what is the name and/or id of each form field.

By the looks of it, I seems like it would be `room[room_name]` when it would need to be `member[room_attributes][room_name]`.

Comment: I believe you are right. I would also consider using Strong Parameters all the way, as suggested by @sircapsalot

Comment: The name of the fields are :room_name and :rent, but from my understanding @member.room in the form_for line gives the field names access to the corresponding param keys.

Comment: What would be the correct syntax for using member:[:room_attributes][:room_name] in the form?

Comment: I believe you would only need to change the opening of your `form_for` to `form_for [@member, @room] do ... `.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Strong Parameters,  Trying using:

```
@member.room.update(rent: member_params[:member][:room_attributes][:rent], room_name: member_params[:member][:room_attributes][:room_name])
```

(`member_params` instead of `params`)

Comment: ok now it says "param is missing or the value is empty: member"